# Strip html for reading

Tags: google-chrome, html, offline-files

I purchased a kindle paperwhite, and I would like to send some webpages for reading to it. I know the process of sending it via email. But the problem is, I would like to 'optimize' the webpages before sending.

I would like to know how to strip the page of its content(sidebar,header,footer etc) and SAVE to an html file(for sending).

Some tool that work like chrome's "inspect element"(hovering over the html elements allow you to view its source) is what 'might' work for me, but I am unsure. Also, I would like to retain the styling of the main content(and save for offline reading)

Comment: Most likely you will have the best luck doing this by copying and pasting the body of the page into a rich text editor (such as Word), then saving the file as html.

Comment: but that didnt work for me. could you please send me a stripped html of this 
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Mylyn/article.html

Comment: Sure, [here](http://www.vogella.com/img/lars/100x120xlars-hackagotchi.png.pagespeed.ic.gx2Sf13j9r.png) it is with _all_ the unimportant bits stripped out for you. That'll be $5. ;)